# can't generate core file after change user from root to nobody in c language

Tags: c, linux, core-file

after change user from root to nobody in **c language**, and I am sure the program core dump, but  always can't generate **core file**.
I'm sure nobody have the right to generate file in current dir. and ulimit -c is unlimited, and I use :

```
system("echo 'tesstestestestestetestestet!!!!!!' >  hahahahhaahahah");
```

after change user from root to nobody, the file hahahahhaahahah was created!

so, I'm very confuse!

here is my c file:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
#if 1
    struct passwd *pw;

    //char *username = "root";
    char *username = "nobody";
    if (getuid() == 0 || geteuid() == 0)
    {
        if (username == 0 || *username == '\0')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't run as root without the -u switch\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if ((pw = getpwnam(username)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't find the user %s to switch to\n", username);
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (setgid(pw->pw_gid) < 0 || setuid(pw->pw_uid) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to assume identity of user %s\n", username);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
#endif

    printf("now user change to group id %d, user id %d\n", getgid(), getuid());

    system("echo 'tesstestestestestetestestet!!!!!!' >  hahahahhaahahah");
    char *test_a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    char *test_b;
    strcpy(test_b, test_a);
    *(char *)1=1;
    printf("test_b:%s\n", test_b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read *carefully* [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) man page:

> There are various circumstances in which a core dump file is not produced:

<sup>.... *skipping some text from the man page* ....</sup>

> - The process is executing a set-user-ID (set-group-ID) program that is owned by a user (group) other than the real user (group) ID of the process.

So basically, after a successful [setuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) syscall, core is *not* dumped.(for security reasons)

See also the Linux specific [prctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) syscall, with `PR_SET_DUMPABLE`.

Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

NB. Have a `nobody` writable directory is probably a bad idea. The `nobody` user should usually not own any file or directory!

Comment: my program is running on nobody user, at least I need to generate logs, so there must be a directory own by nobody. or maybe there is other ways?

Comment: You should use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) for logging.

Comment: usually, user program don't use syslog?   what if I just log by nobody in my way?  I know it's unsafe, but I don't know why.

Comment: Some directories are writable by everyone; You could log into `/var/tmp` or you could have a `nobody` owned `/var/log/myapp.log` and write inside...