# Coredump file not generated when changing user

Tags: c++, coredump

The following code generates coredump file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main() {
    int b = 0;
    int a = 140/b;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Floating point exception (core dumped)`

Coredump is generated in `/opt/cores`

```
$ ls -al /opt/cores
total 188
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   4096 Jan 13 16:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root   4096 Jan 12 11:57 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 344064 Jan 13 16:46 core.prueba.6776.8
```

However, this doesn't generate coredump file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main() {
    std::string usr = "nobody";
    std::string grp = "oinstall";

    group* gp = getgrnam(grp.data());
    passwd* user = getpwnam(usr.data());
    if (gp && user && setgid(gp->gr_gid) == 0 && setuid(user->pw_uid) == 0) {
        std::cout << "changed!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "not changed =(" << std::endl;
    }   
    struct rlimit rlim;
    rlim.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
    rlim.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rlim) != 0) {
        std::cout << "setrlimit error" << std::endl;
    }   

    getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rlim);

    std::cout << "rlim_cur: " << (int)rlim.rlim_cur <<", rlim_max: " << (int)rlim.rlim_max << std::endl;
    int b = 0;
    int a = 140/b;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
changed!
rlim_cur: -1, rlim_max: -1
Floating point exception
```

I've run the first piece of code with the changed user and it generates the coredump file, so the directory has the right permissions. The problem is when I change user in the code. Any clues?

This happens on Linux (CentOS 6, CentOS 7, RHEL 6).

In Solaris works fine.

Comment: Yes, I showed the permissions in the question (777). Maybe it has to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204782/cant-generate-core-file-after-change-user-from-root-to-nobody-in-c-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nos was right about the security mechanism.

The solution was to add this **after** changing user:

`prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0,0,0);`

Now the coredump is generated.

Answer (score 2):

The setuid() manpage has this note:

> If uid is different from the old effective UID, the process will be
>   forbidden from leaving core dumps.

This is a security mechanism, you can read more as to why [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/how-come-no-core-dump-is-create-when-an-application-has-suid-set)

You need to enable the [fs.suid_dumpable](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt) to have your process coredump by doing:

```
 sysctl -w fs.suid_dumpable=2
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to come to a solution within the program instead of changing the system.